# How to set up this polymorphic relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-6

Tables: (only relevant columns included)

- **users**: *id*
- **reviews**: *id*, *user_id*, *reviewable_type*, *reviewable_id*
- **subject_ones**: *id*
- **subject_twos**: *id*

Models: (this is what I've tried)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
end
```

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true

  scope :subject_one, -> { where(reviewable_type: SubjectOne.name) }
end
```

```
class Reviewable < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
end
```

```
class SubjectOne < Reviewable

end
```

```
class SubjectTwo < Reviewable

end
```

The rows in `subject_ones` and `subject_twos` will not really change and the users can elect to include rows from each. The two tables differ enough that they need distinct tables, but the data model for a review itself is the same. The display to the user will be different for the different types as well. `reviews` are unique on `user_id`, `reviewable_type`, and `reviewable_id`

I'd like the end result to be something where I can do `user.reviews.subject_one.first.reviewable` and it returns the first `subject_ones` record.

Basically, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the "reviewable" from the `review`.

Right now if call `user.reviews.subject_one.first.reviewable` I get:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "reviewables" does not exist LINE 8: WHERE a.attrelid = '"reviewables"'::regclass ^
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - the parent class `Reviewable` was missing `self.abstract_class = true` flag. Without this, Rails assumes it should map to a db table, but in this case it should be mapping to the child class' table name.